# How to hyphenate "long-term-oriented portfolio?"

Tags: hyphenation

Do I just use one hyphen, as in:

- long-term oriented portfolio

Or go all in with:

- long-term-oriented portfolio

I feel like the whole thing is a compound adjective because [oriented](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oriented) is also an adjective here, not a verb in the past tense...

Comment: A fine mess someone got you in. Why do you need oriented? Resume much? Team-player detail-oriented, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. long-term-oriented portfolio; or
2. a portfolio oriented long-term